# android - best way to handle saving fragment state when dealing with lots of images and views

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a fragment in an activity where I create views dynamically and assign images to the image views after a user selects them from a gallery I created. However if the user hits the back button and then re-opens the fragment the views have all been reset and there are no images. Ive tried a couple different ways of handling the saved state but since Im dealing with potentially up to 20 images Im not sure how to handle the state of my fragment being that none of the methods ive tried seem to work. Right now Im trying to use Fragment.SavedState and just re instantiate using that but I cant figure out how to actually use the savedstate. Any help or advice on the matter would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best thing to do would be to use an LRU cache, for best performance you would want to combine a memory based cache and a disk based cache.  Jake Wharton has an excellent implementation [here](https://github.com/JakeWharton/DiskLruCache).

Once a Fragment/Activity is no longer visible it up for garbage collection, so you need to be able to rebuild the whole view.  I would recommend testing with `Don't Keep Activities` turned on in the Developer Options.

There is an excellent example of loading images from the Network in [BitmapFun](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html) on the Android Developer site.

Comment: I actually am using a LruCache but for some reason the imageviews get destroyed when the fragment gets replaced. I can go to another activity and comeback just fine but as soon as it is replaced the imageviews reset.

Comment: I have a basic idea of how to do it but how would I go about saving my entire fragment state and then rebuilding it from scratch. I tried that earlier but I got a bunch of nullpointers so Ive been trying evreything else

Comment: I bet with the large number of images in the `View` it is garbage collected very quickly once it is no longer visible.

Comment: If I'm understanding it correctly the user selects an image in the Gallery view and that opens a detail view with a bunch more images.  What I would do in that case is pass in the list of images to load (or whatever you would use to derive that list) to the `Fragment` via `setArguments` on the `Fragment`.  Then I would use an `Adapter` tied to a `ListView` or `GridView` that accepts a list of the images to load.  The `Adapter` would load the image asynchronously from the cache (or pull it down again if not in the cache) and put it in an ImageView.

Comment: I dont know if the views are getting collected but the ondestroy is not getting called

Comment: Actually I have two linear layouts where I have dynamically placed a series relativelayouts containing imageviews and a button. A user hits a button on the relativelayout and opens another activity where they get an image and then are returned to the activity with the fragment. I can go back and forth from the fragment to the other activity no problem and the views stay just fine. but as soon as I replace that fragment with another in the same activity and then go back to it the views have been cleared.

Comment: Hmm, are you checking in `FragmentManager` to see if the old `Fragment` exists? Perhaps it is creating a new `Fragment` each time.

Comment: I didnt bother to check to see if the fragment is being recreated because I made it global and I only instantiated it at the start of my activity in the oncreate. Ill try to check if it exists in the fragment manager but I think that its getting popped off the backstack and then destroyed.

Comment: Ok so I did a work around where I just create a public static Bundle in my fragmentActivity and then in the onpause of the fragment I put some arrays containing keys to my images and then in the oncreateview I just check to see if that data in the bundle is null or not and when its not null I repopulate the views based on the info in the bundle. Its not super fancy but it works. If you have a better solution thats leak proof Id love to hear it but I saw my fragments ondestroy finally get called so I had to use a bundle that wouldnt get killed.